# BiqQuery Left Outer with an OR condition Error

Tags: google-bigquery

Ran into the BigQuery limitation that you can't use an OR on a JOIN.  Runs fine in Oracle.

Looking for some hints on how to accomplish this in another matter.

The last left outer join produces this error.

*LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.*

```
select [col list]
from tablea a
   left outer join tableb b on a.id = b.ID
   left outer join tabled d on a.id = d.iid
   left outer join tablee e on b.id = e.pid and b.cid = e.id
   left outer join tablef f on d.runitid = f.id or e.runitid = f.id
```

Comment: use an `IN statement`

Answer (score 0):

Due to additional join dependencies down the stack I switched it to a JOIN which allows the OR condition.  More verification of results will be done.